# Accessing Axios data (Objects)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, promise, axios

I want "Monthly Time Series" data in this.state={stockOne: []}.
However, as the data formatting of "Monthly Time Series" api does not have [] around objects, I have difficulty accessing data.
Is there a way I can format this to access data and insert in this.state?

EDIT: I was able to console.log(this.state.stockOne) and (this.state.stockOne["2020-02-27"]) with answer below @Mohammed Ashfaq .
However, I cannot pass it to StockOne.js with this.props.stockOne which returns empty [] and this.props.stockOne["2020-02-27"] returning undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import StockOne from '.././component/StockOne/StockOne.js'

const apiKey = '11111111111111';


class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
          this.state={
              stockOne: []
          };    
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=${apiKey}`)
            .then(res=> 
                {this.setState({stockOne:res.data["Monthly Time Series"]},
                console.log(res.data["Monthly Time Series"]),  /*returns {},{},{},...*/
                console.log(res.data), 
                console.log(this.state.stockOne)  /*returns undefined */
                )
            })


    }


    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <StockOne stockOne={this.state.stockOne}/>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

API JSON DATA

```
{
"Meta Data": {
"1. Information": "Monthly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
"2. Symbol": "MSFT",
"3. Last Refreshed": "2020-02-27",
"4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Monthly Time Series": {
"2020-02-27": {
"1. open": "170.4300",
"2. high": "190.7000",
"3. low": "157.9800",
"4. close": "158.1800",
"5. volume": "790184525"
},
"2020-01-31": {
"1. open": "158.7800",
"2. high": "174.0500",
"3. low": "156.5100",
"4. close": "170.2300",
"5. volume": "555989763"
},

 ....}
}
```

Comment: could it be as simple as this? `this.setState( { stockOne: [ res.data["Monthly Time Series"] ] }` ?

Comment: @admcfajin Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

> setState is an asynchronous function So, it won't update the state
>   value immediately. If you want to check the updated value  then
>   pass a callback function as a second argument to setState and print
>   the state vaue inside that cb.

```js
 componentDidMount(){
   axios.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=${apiKey}`)
     .then(res=> {
         this.setState({stockOne:res.data["Monthly Time Series"] },()=> {
             console.log(res.data["Monthly Time Series"]);  /*returns {},{},{},...*/
             console.log(res.data);
             console.log(this.state.stockOne); 
      })
   })
 }
```

The stockOne initial Value should be an empty object {} because the api response res.data["Monthly Time Series"] is also an Object.

> Accessing object values

```js
let User = {name:"steve"}
 //There are two way's to access an Object value

//1. Dot notation
console.log(User.name)

//2. Bracket Notation

console.log(User['name'])
```

Comment: thank you. I can console.log(this.state.stockOne) now. However it is still individual {},{}. How would I enter into [] array so I can pick out certain by certain time?
this.state.stockOne[2019-01-31] returns error. Is there a way to access data individually?

Comment: try this  this.state.stockOne["2020-02-27"]

Comment: Okay another problem. even though in the function, this.state.stockOne["2020-02-27"], I can't seem to access this.props.stockOne["2020-02-27"] in StockOne.js.